# Error: 18 in java IDE

Tags: java, class, enums

How can I fix this error in Java:

> ```
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - class EnumTest
> is public, should be declared in a file named EnumTest.java
> at EnumTest.<clinit>(Day.java:18)
>  Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
> ```

[image: please help me[![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]:]

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] in the question itself?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your public class definition in its own class file. Move the class to a file named `EnumTest.java`.